# Permission denied in a Docker container even if user has the rights

Tags: tomcat, docker, rights

Here is what I do:

```
$ docker run -it --rm tomcat:8.5-alpine sh
/usr/local/tomcat # adduser -D -g '' -u 1000 user
/usr/local/tomcat # chown -R user:user $CATALINA_HOME
/usr/local/tomcat # su user -c 'catalina.sh run'
sh: catalina.sh: Permission denied

/usr/local/tomcat # echo $CATALINA_HOME
/usr/local/tomcat
/usr/local/tomcat # ls -la $CATALINA_HOME
total 128
drwxr-xr-x   20 user     user          4096 Dec  4 00:47 .
drwxr-xr-x   10 root     root          4096 Dec  4 00:47 ..
-rw-r-----    1 user     user         57092 Nov  3 21:16 LICENSE
-rw-r-----    1 user     user          1723 Nov  3 21:16 NOTICE
-rw-r-----    1 user     user          7063 Nov  3 21:16 RELEASE-NOTES
-rw-r-----    1 user     user         15946 Nov  3 21:16 RUNNING.txt
drwxr-x---    2 user     user          4096 Dec  4 00:47 bin
drwx------    2 user     user          4096 Dec  4 00:47 conf
drwxr-xr-x    4 user     user          4096 Dec  4 00:47 include
drwxr-x---    2 user     user          4096 Dec  4 00:47 lib
drwxr-x---    2 user     user          4096 Nov  3 21:14 logs
drwxr-xr-x    4 user     user          4096 Dec  4 00:47 native-jni-lib
drwxr-x---    2 user     user          4096 Dec  4 00:47 temp
drwxr-x---   12 user     user          4096 Dec  4 00:47 webapps
drwxr-x---    2 user     user          4096 Nov  3 21:14 work

/usr/local/tomcat # su user -c 'ls -la /usr/local/tomcat/bin'
ls: can't open '/usr/local/tomcat/bin': Permission denied
total 0

/usr/local/tomcat # su user -c 'ls -la /usr/local/tomcat/include'
total 12
drwxr-xr-x    4 user     user          4096 Dec  4 00:47 .
drwxr-xr-x   20 user     user          4096 Dec  4 00:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 user     user          4096 Nov 17 23:45 apr-1
```

I don't understand why my new created user `user` can't access to `/usr/local/tomcat/bin` whereas he can access to `/usr/local/tomcat/include`: `user` has all user's & group's rights over this `bin` folder...

I've got the same results if I lauch docker with `--privileged=true` (`docker run --privileged=true -it --rm tomcat:8.5-alpine sh`), and this Docker image doesn't seem to use SELinux as `su -c "setenforce 0"` gives the error `ash: setenforce: not found`.

I'm using Docker version `1.12.3, build 6b644ec` on Ubuntu `14.04.5 LTS`.

Is this corresponding to a [bug in Docker with AUFS driver](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24660)?

Comment: Haven't you found any solution yet?

Comment: @rideronthestorm sadly no, I finally ran Tomcat as root: https://github.com/anthony-o/SwinGifts/blob/master/run_with_docker.sh#L89 . I think it is due to a bug in Docker with AUFS driver: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24660

Comment: @rideronthestorm or perhaps in your case it is a "chmod THEN chown" problem? see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6047#issuecomment-270156862

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a [Security-Enhance Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) issue.

Try first:

```
su -c "setenforce 0"
```

Or use [`--privileged` when using `docker run`](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/26029)

```
docker run --privileged=true -it --rm tomcat:8.5-alpine sh
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't do the job as I precise it in my question...